# SFINAE doesn't detect T::reference

Tags: c++, stl, sfinae

The `std::vector<T>` class is a model of the STL Container concept, and as such any proper implementation of vector has to include a nested typedef `value_type` as well as `reference`.  This should be detectable using SFINAE.  However, in my own tests, I can use SFINAE to detect a nested `value_type` typedef, but for some reason I *can't* detect `reference`.

```
template <class T> 
typename T::value_type* test(T)
{
    cout << "Has nested typedef!" << endl;
}

template <class T> 
void test(...)
{
    cout << "Doesn't have nested typedef!" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    test(std::vector<int>());
}
```

This outputs: `Has nested typedef!`

However, if I replace `value_type` with `reference`, like:

```
template <class T> 
typename T::reference* test(T)
{
    cout << "Has nested typedef!" << endl;
}

template <class T> 
void test(...)
{
    cout << "Doesn't have nested typedef!" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    test(std::vector<int>());
}
```

...the program fails to compile at all, giving the error: `error: no matching function for call to test(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >)`

Why does the SFINAE technique work with `T::value_type` but not with `T::reference`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What's a pointer to a reference?

**A**: Impossible. Pointers to references cannot exist, so neither of your functions can exist. This is in contrast to your first case, where at least one of the functions can exist (and thus you get compilation, linkage and output).

Interestingly, SFINAE *is* working here, as the function definition is not causing the compilation error. It's attempting to call a function that, because of impossibility+SFINAE, doesn't exist, that's causing the error. :)

Comment: [quite deliberately an answer, not a comment]

Comment: Perhaps someone should point out his obvious error of the `(...)` not deducing the `T`, so that it can never be called because of that reason. Apparently, @Channel figured it out, and you did too, but an innocent visitor may not be able to.

Comment: @litb: +1. I missed that, actually.

Answer (score 2):

> typename T::reference* test(T)

Pointers to references are illegal in C++.

§8.3.2/4 from the Standard says:

> There shall be no references to references, no arrays of references, and **no pointers to references**.